# Spectrum of randomly projected matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, random-matrices

Consider a random projection of some deterministic positive $m\times m$ Hermitian matrix $A$, defined as $B:=PUAU^\dagger P$, where the $m\times m$ unitary matrix $U$ is Haar random and $P$ is some fixed $m\times m$ projector with rank $n<m$. Does the spectrum of $B$ typically match approximately (up to normalisation) with the spectrum of $A$ ordered in decreasing order at the first $n$ eigenvalues?

(I'm not sure how to formulate the approximation precisely. Presumably I want the spectral distributions to be close as $n,m$ become large enough.)

Related [post](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/412112/typical-eigenspectrum-of-a-random-projection-of-a-large-matrix) at mathoverflow, but it is not yet answered.

Comment: Could you say what you call Haar random vectors ?

Comment: You have written $B=PAP$. Isn't it $B=P^TAP$ ? Besides, could you give the resp. dimensions of $A,B,P$ ?

Comment: Do you mean "let $v_1,\cdots,v_k$ be the first $k$ columns of a Haar unitary, let $P$ be the orthogonal projection on the subspace they span, and let $A$ be a random Hermitian matrix (according to which law, btw?); can you help me understand the spectrum of $PAP$?"?

Comment: @JeanMarie A "projection" in this case refers to a matrix $P$ with $P = P^T = P^2$; in general, its codomain is distinct from its image. If the columns of $U$ form an orthonormal basis for the image of $P$, then $P = UU^T$ and $PAP$ will have the same non-zero eigenvalues as $U^TAU$.

Comment: @Ben Grossmann Thanks: it is much clearer. I am surprized by the discrepancy between this question and the (similar ?) question referenced in MathOverflow.

Comment: Sorry guys~ Hopefully now it is clearer and I think it is the same problem as in the MO post.

Comment: You haven't answered me about the definition of "Haar random vectors" which is not a classical term.

Comment: @JeanMarie I've reformulated the question that doesn't use "Haar random vectors" any more.

Comment: You say in this version that your matrix is positive (definite positive ?) but in the MO post, you only say that it is symmetric...

Comment: @JeanMarie well, that MO post isn't by me, consider what I asked here a slightly different version than the MO one.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is no. The largest eigenvalue of $PAP$ will match that of $A$ if and only if the eigenvector $x$ of $A$ associated with the largest eigenvalue of $A$ is an element of the range of $P$. However, for a given vector $x$, a "random" projection $P$ will contain $x$ with probability zero since the set of such projections is a proper Zariski closed subset of the set of projections.